# The JavaVM.framework. What is it? How could I use it?

Tags: java, objective-c

In playing around with Xcode recently, there is a framework named `JavaVM.framework`. What is this framework for, and how could I use it?

Would this allow me to somehow build Objective-C applications that use Java libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaVM.framework is the Objective-C <> Java bridge, more information here:
http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000024.php